# A group word having no trivial proper subword

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, combinatorics-on-words

The question is: what is the object in the title called, if it has been defined elsewhere?

Let $G$
be a group generated by a finite set $S\subset G$.
A *word*
of length $k$
in $S$
is a string $w=s_1\dots s_k$
where: $\forall i$,
$s_i\in S$
or $s_i^{-1}\in S$.
Eliminating a subword of the form $s_i^{\mp1}s_{i}^{\pm1}$
is called a *reduction*,
and performing any series of reductions on $w$
until there are no such subwords left results in the unique *reduced*
word $\overline w$.

Now interpret a word $w=s_1\dots s_k$
as a product in $G$,
with the empty word corresponding to the identity $e$.
The *word problem* for $G$
is to find an algorithm that determines when $w\sim e$.
Every word satisfies $\overline w=e\Rightarrow w\sim e$,
but the converse to this only holds when $G$
is the free group over $S$.

One thing we might think about is generalizing the cancellations to subwords $s_i\dots s_{i+j}\sim1$.
Applying a sequence of such cancellations does not,
in general,
determine a unique word like it did with reduction
(e.g., trivial subwords can overlap),
and the subtleties of this capture important details of the word problem.
Motivated by that,
the *irreducible word problem*
is to find an algorithm that determines when a word admitting no proper trivial subword is trivial.
When $G$
is finite,
the length of such words is bounded by $|G|$.

I'm interested in the vocabulary for the mechanics of this,
to help me navigate the literature.
What do we call the removal of a subword of the form $s_i\dots s_{i+j}\sim1$? (Cancellation?)
Finally,
what do we call a word having the property that it admits no proper subword equivalent to the identity?
(The term "irreducible"
would make sense to me if it were consistent with representation theory,
but it does not seem to be.)
If a geometric approach is desired,
these are the 2-cycles and simple closed curves on the Cayley graph.

Comment: I recommend that you read (at least the beginning of) Magnus *et al.*'s, *"Combinatorial Group Theory [. . .]"*.

Comment: @Shaun I'm seeing the usual setup and definitions, and it seems to go into the area I'm interested in, but what I really want is a standard term for the type of word I described. Is there such a thing in that reference?

Comment: On closer inspection, I guess not. But that's where I'd look at any rate. I'm sorry I'm not of much help here.

Comment: @Shaun No prob and thanks anyway. Maybe it's just simply, a trivial word with no trivial subwords. I'm happy to make up my own catchy term for it and move on but want to pay my dues.

Comment: The set of such words is sometimes called the *reduced word problem* or the *irreducible word problem* of the group, so you could try searching for theses terms (in quotes). The references I found were investigating the formal language class of this set of words.

Comment: @DerekHolt From what I'm seeing, a word of that type is defined as having no proper trivial prefix. This is different, no? For instance, consider the presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^3\rangle$ and the word $baaab^{-1}$. It does not satisfy my condition, but has no proper trivial prefix.

Comment: The refences I found for irreducible word problem (such as [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40164-0_27)) define it to be the words equal to the identity but with no proper subwords equal to the identity. Perhaps I got that wrong and *reduced word problem* means having no proper prefixes equal to identity.

Comment: You can view your condition in terms of diagrams with no cut $0$-cells. Such a cut point falls along a "ladder", which is a more general concept but plays a role in small cancellation theory and the work of Dani Wise. Google "fans and ladders in small cancellation theory".

Comment: @DerekHolt I see what you mean. It seems as though *reduced* and *irreducible* can mean two different things, yet are sometimes used interchangeably. I think I'm going to revise my question so that it's more about getting consensus on the standard definitions.

Comment: For your new edits, the idea of "Dehn reduced" is relevant. Writing $\mathbf{r}^*$ for the set of all cyclic shifts of relators and their inverses, a word $w$ is *Dehn reduced* if there is no $R\in\mathbf{r}^*$ such that $R$ decomposes as $R_0
R_1$ with $|R_0|>|R_1|$ and $R_0$ is a subword of $w$. (Much easier in terms of diagrams: there is no relator-diagram on the boundary of the word such that the external path is longer than the internal path, so no "bulges".)

Comment: (A *Dehn presentation* is a presentation such that every non-empty, reduced word $w$ representing the trivial element is not Dehn reduced. This gives a linear-time solution to the word problem. A group is hyperbolic if and only if it admits a Dehn presentation.)

Comment: @user1729 That is interesting and makes me want to read more about that. But I also just want a clean term for the types of words I'm describing, that won't clash with the literature. My characterization of the words is very easy and intuitive. I imagine it's not equivalent to being Dehn reduced or they wouldn't go through all that trouble defining it the way you gave.

Comment: There is a technical difference between a group word and the evaluation of a group word in a particular group. The definition of reduced that you give is for the word, not for the evaluation of word in $G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think you are referring to the distinction between the words and their equivalence class as representing an element of a group. I'm also aware of saying a word is "reduced" with respect to length among representatives of an element. I'm still not sure if this helps with what we call a word that has no trivial subwords.

Comment: @j0equ1nn: Well, “trivial subword” of length greater than 2 only occurs if you are thinking about the *value* of the (sub)word in the particular group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree. So perhaps the term "reduced" is just about words, or just about words in free groups. The question remains: what do we call the words I characterized when we are thinking of them as pertaining to a particular group and presentation? If there is no such term, that would also constitute an answer, in which case I'll go ahead and make a term up myself.

Comment: If we focus on the Wikipedia treatment (which seems a decent reflection of the literature), a word is defined only after specifying a group and using letters from a given generating set. We could alternatively define a word and a reduced word on a set equipped with inverses, with no relations ... but typically we don't. So why ignore other relations? This is perhaps the crux of the confusion here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Digging in to what you said a bit brought me to some helpful literature. Thanks! I think this question may be worth another revision...